# URL field is out of bounds when I mark a question as a duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, google-chrome

Should it be like this?

[image] 
Google Chrome, Windows 10, no zoom.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on _Windows 2012 R2_ too. So I hope windows-10 tag is not exactly required here.